# How to convert Lambda into simple Java function expression

Tags: android, lambda

I don't want to use java `VERSION_1_8` in my module.
but in a snippet code from a library it using this code :

```
    RxPaparazzo.takeImage(this)
            .crop(options)
            .size(size)
            .usingGallery()
            .subscribe(response -> {
                if (response.resultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    response.targetUI().showUserCanceled();
                    return;
                }

                // Log.e("response",response.data());

                response.targetUI().loadImage(response.data());
            });
```

now how can I change it to simple java function expression ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can change it to anonymous class using the following trick in Android Studio

1. Click on "->" or Get the cursor on "->"
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> on Mac)
3. Select Replace lambda with anonymous class.

Screenshot to explain:

[image: Steps]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Thank you very much. exactly what I wanted. :)

Comment: Perfect, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it should be some thing along the line of the following.

```
   RxPaparazzo.takeImage(this)
        .crop(options)
        .size(size)
        .usingGallery()
        .subscribe(new _ON_CALLBACK_LISTENER ()
        {
            @Override
            void _ON_CALLBACK (_FIELD_TYPE response){
                if (response.resultCode() != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    response.targetUI().showUserCanceled();
                    return;
                }

                // Log.e("response",response.data());

                response.targetUI().loadImage(response.data());
        }});
```

you need to know the listenerType (_ON_CALLBACK_LISTENER) 
and also the parameterType (_FIELD_TYPE)

just hover over the codes, and there should be some hints, and Alt-Enter may auto generate the code stubs for you.